# Ticks number for nvd3 cumulativechart not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, coffeescript, nvd3.js

I am using nvd3 library cumulativeChart with coffee-script and I have an issue with ticks (xAxis) on my graph, the dates are overlapping each other when the date range is too big.
Any ideas how to solve this issue?
[Image for Nvd3 cumulativeChart ticks (xAxis) issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuJGf.png)

Here is the code

```
chart = nv.models.cumulativeLineChart()
        .x((d) ->
          d[0] )
        .y((d) ->
          d[2])
        .color(d3.scale.category10().range())
        .useInteractiveGuideline(true)

     chart.xAxis
        .axisLabel('Dates')
        .ticks(3) // doesn't show 3 ticks shows every time differently
        .tickFormat((d)->
          d3.time.format('%d/%m/%Y')(new Date(d)))

     chart.yAxis.axisLabel('Percents').tickFormat(d3.format(',r'))

     $('#d3-graph').append('<svg></svg>')
     graph = d3.select('#d3-graph svg').datum(dataSet).call(chart)

     nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update)
     console.log(dataSet)
     chart
```

---

And here is a shorter version of my dataSet

```
dataSet =
[{
"key": "Series 1",
"values": [ [ 1025409600000 , 0] , [ 1028088000000 , -6.3382185140371]]
}]
```

Any ideas how to get the ticks to be exactly 3?

Comment: shouldn't be `.y((d) -> d[1])` instead of `.y((d) -> d[2])` . I don't know about nvd3.. but I thought It could be a typo...

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right it is a typo it is supposed to be  .y((d) -> d[1]) thanks for noticing it!